# Meteor JS - How to access posts programmatically in Telescope app

Tags: meteor, telescope

I have recently started using Telescope (http://www.telesc.pe/) from the creators of Meteor for a small project. I am just starting to learn about Meteor, and since essentially database / web server and application stack are collapsed into one framework, I'm wondering what the most efficient way is for me to have an external application (for ex: python script) post and access posts/comments from Telescope. Essentially, I'd like a bot to be able to:

- Create posts
- Add comments to posts
- Pull back a list of posts

Ideally I'd like to access this via HTTP requests (get/post/etc), but am not sure how to do this within telescope / meteor or possibly DB queries. Any help (such as an example API call to create a new post) or the appropriate way to do this using Meteor would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.telesc.pe/docs/packages/) it doesn't look like Telescope has a webservice API and there aren't any plans for it on the [roadmap](https://trello.com/b/oLMMqjVL/telescope-roadmap) either.

Luckily meteor has a packaging system, which telescope already uses a lot.
So you could make a meteor package that hooks into telescope and exposes webservices for the functionality you described.

Meteorpedia has a good article on how to create rest api's in meteor: [here](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API)

Answer (score 0):

Telescope has a basic API.  You can see a sample response here...
http://meta.telesc.pe/api

And here's the package that makes that happen.
https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/tree/master/packages/telescope-api

You could copy and extend that package to accomplish whatever you need.