# Meteor JS - How import posts and comments to Telescope

Tags: meteor, telescope

I need to import some posts and their comments into my Telescope project.
Is their a good way to do this?

It is really the same question like:
[Meteor JS - How to access posts programmatically in Telescope app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430468/meteor-js-how-to-access-posts-programmatically-in-telescope-app)

Comment: I`m not sure if I follow. You want to import some posts and their comment (from where?) into your Telescope project? Or the opposite? Import the post of Telescope on another system?

Comment: The posts and comments are from my own file, like json or xml. And I need to import such files into Telescope system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import an RSS feed, you can use the `post-by-feed` plugin:

https://github.com/xavcz/nova-post-by-feed

If you need to import from a JSON file or some other API, you'll have to write a script yourself. You can look at the `getting-started` package to see how to insert posts and comments on the server.